# Stream videos from Azure Blob Storage using Media Service

Tags: azure, video, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I am developing application which contains Video Library.
We have only 1 Storage account and Users uploading videos on defined Blob container.

Now i want to stream videos stored at Blob using Azure Media Service.
What should i do & which are the efficient steps to perform.?

How can i decrease the video bandwidth for open same video every time by user?

What is the best practice to upload videos by which my video can be played in all devices?

Kindly guide me with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand this correctly, you're uploading your videos directly to Azure Storage? If that's the case, instead of uploading your videos directly to Azure Storage, my suggestion would be to upload your videos using the Azure Media Services SDK. Your videos will be stored as an `Asset` file which will make it easier to stream video to different devices.

Here's a guide for doing that using .NET http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-get-started/

Azure Media Services has pretty good documentation which might help with your other asks http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/media-services/resources/

Comment: Yes Michael you are right. Don't i need to upload videos on Blob in place of Media service.? I was planning that first i will upload videos to Blob and then copy videos to Azure Media service by creating Assets.

Thanks for your valuable response.

Comment: Hi Harsh. You don't need to upload to Blobs in place of Media Services. Once you've created your Media Services account, just follow the guidance for [uploading a file using Media Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-get-started/#create-a-new-asset-and-upload-a-video-file).

Comment: @MichaelCurd-MSFT Hello Michael, I tried installing Media Services in a Windows Universal application but I can't do it because the `TransientFaultHandling.Core` dependency cannot be installed in a project with this version of .NET. So I am doing it the OP's way. Also, as far as I know you can't upload a stream to media services directly.